# Vue js obtain boolean value from an input tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm struggling my mind on how to obtain a boolean value from an input text if there is typed text inside or not. I mean I would like to know how to obtain true/false from an text input tag depending if it contains text or not.
I'm using Vue js 2.

Comment: Are you creating a component that accepts input?

Comment: `inputElement.value.length.trim() > 0`?

Comment: @samayo yea im creating an html input tag type="text"

Comment: use Vue's binding and check the model in your controller

Answer (score 0):

you could use a computed variable:

```
<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="text"/>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'TestComponent',
        data(){
            return {
                text:''
            }
        },
        computed: {
            isFilled(){
                return this.text.trim().length > 0
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```